# How can I get in my API the slug passed (slug=${params.slug})

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How can I get in my API the slug passed (`slug=${params.slug}`,`)
I'm working with vercel AI SDK

```js
  const { messages, input, handleInputChange, handleSubmit, isLoading, error } =
    useChat({
      api: `/api/conversation?slug=${params.slug}`,
    });
```

My API / Not getting the slug:

```js
export async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    const { userId } = auth();
    const body = await req.json();
    const { messages, slug } = body;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use req.query for accessing the query string.

Or use req.params by keeping the template of api as `/api/conversation/:slug`
and you will get something like `console.log(req.params) // Output: {slug: 'Your Slug'}`

Comment: that's not working, what I tried:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77835277/19854680

Answer (score 0):

What I tried but not working, I only get the error:

```
export async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    const { userId } = auth();
    const body = await req.json();
    const { messages } = body;
    const { chatId } = req.params;

    return NextResponse.json(chatId);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("[CONVERSATION_ERROR]", error);
    return NextResponse.json({
      error: "An error occurred while processing the request.",
    });
  }
```

for that call :

```
  const {
    messages,
    setMessages,
    input,
    handleInputChange,
    handleSubmit,
    isLoading,
    error,
  } = useChat({
    api: `/api/conversation?chatId=${params.slug}`,
  });
```